# IPad screen mirroring performance

Tags: ipad, mirroring

I have tried screen mirroring on an ipad using the code from:

http://code.google.com/p/iphoneos-screen-mirroring/

The problem is that it is extremely slow and bad performance (e.g. on a cross fade animation).
I have tried various refresh rates but without any luck.

Am I doing something wrong or is this generally slow on ipads?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the technique it uses is resource intensive.  You need to wind the mirroring framerate way down (e.g. 5 fps was fine for my needs).  You won't see smooth animations on the external screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Rob Terrell's TVOutManager](http://github.com/robterrell/TVOutManager)